# JavaScript === vs == for type checking

Tags: javascript

Which of the following lines is correct?...

```
if (typeof value == 'boolean') { return value; }
```

... or ...

```
if (typeof value === 'boolean') { return value; }
```

I thought the double equal sign was a type of "soft compare" so the `value` variable could either be a `string` or formal type.  Is this not so?  I wonder because JSHint complained about the first version.  I've changed it but now I'm worried that `typeof` won't return a string.

Comment: `typeof` will always be consistent. When in doubt read the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: Both are "correct", but `===` is generally preferred because it's almost always the expected behaviour.

Comment: So, does this mean there are not types in JS?  If so, then why would `typeof` return a string instead of a `type`.

Comment: Again...read the docs to answer last comment

Comment: Many consider `==` and `!=` to be bad practice, and always use the strict versions `===` and `!==` even when the type is known to be the same. Being consistent is also probably *slightly* better for GZIP.

Comment: @G.Deward _"why would typeof return a string instead of a type."_ Because it's designed to return a string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: @JLRishe You're right.  Guess it just feels odd coming from C# where an actual type would be returned.

Comment: Nothing here you couldn't have researched yourself easily

Answer (score 2):

`==` is a soft compare, but `typeof` always returns a string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof